# Why doesn't kibana display all the search results?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Here is my search query:

```
GET /bank/_search?q=*&sort=account_number:asc&pretty
```

which matches all of the 1000 docs in the bank index:

```
health status index                uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   bank                 LRl6fcZsSR6a0BMxIAQzIA   1   1       1000            0    414.3kb        414.3kb
green  open   .kibana_task_manager 2hiY91XzQQKAzmnXhpQLTA   1   0          2            0     12.8kb         12.8kb
green  open   .kibana_1            G4vY0_JASzqERwKlbqMqAg   1   0          4            0     14.7kb         14.7kb
yellow open   customer             0B2gsBy3Rp-5vkMFhto-Wg   1   1          2            0      6.7kb          6.7kb
```

Below are my search results.  Under "hits" at the top, you can see that there were 1000 hits, which is what I expected (all the _docs).  Yet, kibana only displays 9 of the hits.  Where are the rest?

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1000,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 0,
          "balance" : 16623,
          "firstname" : "Bradshaw",
          "lastname" : "Mckenzie",
          "age" : 29,
          "gender" : "F",
          "address" : "244 Columbus Place",
          "employer" : "Euron",
          "email" : "bradshawmckenzie@euron.com",
          "city" : "Hobucken",
          "state" : "CO"
        },
        "sort" : [
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 1,
          "balance" : 39225,
          "firstname" : "Amber",
          "lastname" : "Duke",
          "age" : 32,
          "gender" : "M",
          "address" : "880 Holmes Lane",
          "employer" : "Pyrami",
          "email" : "amberduke@pyrami.com",
          "city" : "Brogan",
          "state" : "IL"
        },
        "sort" : [
          1
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 2,
          "balance" : 28838,
          "firstname" : "Roberta",
          "lastname" : "Bender",
          "age" : 22,
          "gender" : "F",
          "address" : "560 Kingsway Place",
          "employer" : "Chillium",
          "email" : "robertabender@chillium.com",
          "city" : "Bennett",
          "state" : "LA"
        },
        "sort" : [
          2
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 3,
          "balance" : 44947,
          "firstname" : "Levine",
          "lastname" : "Burks",
          "age" : 26,
          "gender" : "F",
          "address" : "328 Wilson Avenue",
          "employer" : "Amtap",
          "email" : "levineburks@amtap.com",
          "city" : "Cochranville",
          "state" : "HI"
        },
        "sort" : [
          3
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 4,
          "balance" : 27658,
          "firstname" : "Rodriquez",
          "lastname" : "Flores",
          "age" : 31,
          "gender" : "F",
          "address" : "986 Wyckoff Avenue",
          "employer" : "Tourmania",
          "email" : "rodriquezflores@tourmania.com",
          "city" : "Eastvale",
          "state" : "HI"
        },
        "sort" : [
          4
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 5,
          "balance" : 29342,
          "firstname" : "Leola",
          "lastname" : "Stewart",
          "age" : 30,
          "gender" : "F",
          "address" : "311 Elm Place",
          "employer" : "Diginetic",
          "email" : "leolastewart@diginetic.com",
          "city" : "Fairview",
          "state" : "NJ"
        },
        "sort" : [
          5
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 6,
          "balance" : 5686,
          "firstname" : "Hattie",
          "lastname" : "Bond",
          "age" : 36,
          "gender" : "M",
          "address" : "671 Bristol Street",
          "employer" : "Netagy",
          "email" : "hattiebond@netagy.com",
          "city" : "Dante",
          "state" : "TN"
        },
        "sort" : [
          6
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 7,
          "balance" : 39121,
          "firstname" : "Levy",
          "lastname" : "Richard",
          "age" : 22,
          "gender" : "M",
          "address" : "820 Logan Street",
          "employer" : "Teraprene",
          "email" : "levyrichard@teraprene.com",
          "city" : "Shrewsbury",
          "state" : "MO"
        },
        "sort" : [
          7
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 8,
          "balance" : 48868,
          "firstname" : "Jan",
          "lastname" : "Burns",
          "age" : 35,
          "gender" : "M",
          "address" : "699 Visitation Place",
          "employer" : "Glasstep",
          "email" : "janburns@glasstep.com",
          "city" : "Wakulla",
          "state" : "AZ"
        },
        "sort" : [
          8
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "bank",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "account_number" : 9,
          "balance" : 24776,
          "firstname" : "Opal",
          "lastname" : "Meadows",
          "age" : 39,
          "gender" : "M",
          "address" : "963 Neptune Avenue",
          "employer" : "Cedward",
          "email" : "opalmeadows@cedward.com",
          "city" : "Olney",
          "state" : "OH"
        },
        "sort" : [
          9
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay:

```
hits.hits – actual array of search results (defaults to first 10 documents)
```

You can control the size of what kibana outputs like this:

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "size": 50
}
```

If size isn't specified:

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
}
```

then size defaults to 10.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `size` parameter is set to a value of `10` and therefore you are able to see only 10 results. To get more results you can adjust this parameter according to you needs. Sometimes it would be better to use `size` parameter along with `from` parameter to get results page wise as in when not whole data is required in one go.

So either you can use `"size": 1000` or you can set `"from": 0, "size": 100` to get first 100 results and the keep on sending same query and just change the value of `from` param on each request. For e.g. to get next 100 results set `"from": 100`.

To get all 1000 results add `size` param as below:

```
{
  "query":{
    // your query here
  },
  "size": 1000
}
```

You can read more on from/size [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).

As a query parameter you can add size as

```
GET /bank/_search?q=*&sort=account_number:asc&size=1000&pretty
```